# Syntax error when using Convert inside PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I need to convert my values to Varchar.  I've got this code:

```
SELECT Value AS FieldName, [42] AS [KeyID_42],[600] AS [KeyID_600]
FROM
(
  SELECT TransID, Value, FieldName
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT TransID, [ErisaPlanEndsMM], [ErisaPlanEndsDD],
           [MLRAvgLivesNumber], [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]
      FROM tblSQLAdminInventory
  ) p
  UNPIVOT
   (FieldName FOR Value IN 
      (Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM],
       Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD],
       Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber],
       Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear])
   )AS unpvt
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(FieldName)
FOR TransID IN ([42],[600])
) AS PivotTable
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Convert'.
```

All I've found online is cases where `CAST` was used, because the user needed to convert to Int.  In my case, I want everything Varchar.  Can anyone tell me the proper way to accomplish this?

I should add that this is a dynamic query and may contain several dozen fields, depending on the table.  My code above is the SQL generated when run against one specific table.

Comment: Just a thought, try to use the type without the size like `Convert(VarChar, yourField)`

Comment: Also, what is your SQL-Server version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to convert inside of your `unpivot`, that's not valid syntax. The data needs to be converted **prior** to attempting to unpivot.

You can fix this by putting your convert inside your subquery:

```
SELECT TransID, Value, FieldName
FROM 
(
    SELECT TransID, 
       Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsMM]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsMM], 
       Convert(VarChar(250), [ErisaPlanEndsDD]) AS [ErisaPlanEndsDD],
       Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesNumber]) AS [MLRAvgLivesNumber], 
       Convert(VarChar(250), [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]) AS [MLRAvgLivesRptYear]
    FROM tblSQLAdminInventory
) p
UNPIVOT
(
    FieldName FOR Value IN 
      ([ErisaPlanEndsMM], [ErisaPlanEndsDD], [MLRAvgLivesNumber], [MLRAvgLivesRptYear])
)AS unpvt
```